# How can I manually enter tabs (possibly .vimrc file)?

Tags: vim, tabs

Whenever I try to enter tabs in vim, it just enters 4 spaces. I am currently writing a makefile so I need to be able to enter literal tabs. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove `set expandtab` from your `.vimrc`.  To insert a literal tab when expandtab is on, you can use `Ctrl+v Tab`

Comment: In insert mode, both `<C-i>` and `<C-v><Tab>` will insert a literal tab.

Comment: This is something that should be automatic for your makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `set expandtab` from (or use `set noexpandtab` in) your .vimrc.

To insert a literal tab when expandtab is on, you can use <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+q</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> on windows with the default settings)

Answer (score 0):

in your .vimrc you want
`set noexpandtab`

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, `expandtab` is automatically reset for Makefile

```
:verbose set et?
```

shows

```
noexpandtab
    Last set from C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\ftplugin\make.vim
```

even though I have `se et` in my $MYVIMRC

Try adding

```
filetype plugin on
```

to your $MYVIMRC