# How to set up vim allowing to use tabs and 4spaces

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I want normally always use four spaces to indent code.
Unfortunately for example Makefiles enforce the use of tabs as separator.

My idea now was to set the tab key to four spaces and some extra key (e.g. tab + shift) for the real tabs.

How do I set something like this up?

Currently my ~/.vimrc looks like:

```
syntax on
:set tabstop=4
:set cindent
:set autoindent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> will insert a literal tab, even if `expandtab` is set. If you prefer, you can map this to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> with `:inoremap <s-tab> <c-v><tab>`.

Answer (score 6):

You may prefer something like this as well:

```
set expandtab
autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab
```

This will always convert tabs to spaces, except when you are editing Makefiles.

Comment: In my experience this works out of the box on default installations. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14834048/85371

Answer (score 2):

You need to use shiftwidth, e.g.,

```
:set shiftwidth=4
:set expandtab
```

You may also need to use this command to convert existing tabs to spaces:

```
:retab
```

Comment: can I than still use native tabs?

Comment: and how do I now do a real tab?

Comment: You can use <C-v><tab> when in insert mode to insert a real tab.

Answer (score 0):

`:filetype plugin on` should be enough to have the tab key always insert real tabs in makefiles, using file type detection.
See `:help vimrc-filetype`.

Answer (score 0):

While I generally prefer to convert everything to spaces, I have a specific command in my .vimrc to prevent doing so in makefiles. First I activate expandtab and set shiftwidth, but then I turn off expandtab for makefiles. Order is important here.

```
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
if has('autocmd')
    autocmd FileType make set noexpandtab
endif
```

I also recommend the following, as they are somewhat related and possibly helpful:

```
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set autoindent
```